# get unique values from array but also display the amount of duplicates it had (javascript - reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display unique values in my component but also have a counter next to it to tell me how many duplicates it had

```
const data = [
  {id: 555, name: 'Sales', person: 'Jordan'},
  {id: 555, name: 'Sales', person: 'Bob'},
  {id: 555, name: 'Sales', person: 'John'},
  {id: 777, name: 'Accounts Payable', person: 'Rhoda'},
  {id: 777, name: 'Accounts Payable', person: 'Harry'},
  {id: 888, name: 'IT', person: 'Joe'},
  {id: 888, name: 'IT', person: 'Jake'},
]
```

The snippet below gives a unique array which I map through in my component - How would I modify this to also allow me to show like a counter to see how many duplicates it had

```
let unique = data.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(t=>(t.id === v.id))===i)

function App() {
return (
<div>
  {unique.map((arr) => (
    <p>{arr.name}    {amount of duplicate}</p>
  ))}
  </div>
  )
 }
```

Comment: As an aside, what you are essentially looking for is a "Group By" function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) where id is the key, something like this:

```
data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
   const count =  acc[cur.id]?.count || 0;
   acc[cur.id] = {...cur, count: count + 1};
   return acc;
}, {})
```

Or if you want it in array format you can go for this option but it would be less efficient:

```
data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
   const existingItem = acc.find(item => cur.id === item.id);
   if(existingItem) {
      existingItem.count++;
   }
   else {
      acc.push({...cur, count: 1});    
   }
   return acc;
}, [])
```

Comment: I decided to go with the array one - fantastic implementation - done exactly what I wanted. I need to take a look into reduce to understand exactly what you done

Comment: Basically you iterate over the array and create an accumulator depending on some conditions, same thing can be achieved with a regular for loop it's not rocket science. Reduce should be used for aggregation, in cases where you want to get the sum of an array or you want to group them according to a field like in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The first way that comes to mind is to use a `forEach()` instead of a `map()` and when a duplicate is encountered, increment a counter inside the appropriate `unique` entry.

A probably less efficient way would be to run a `filter()` query on `data` comparing it to your `arr` value.

Answer (score 0):

this is an alternative:

```
    var unique = {}
    data.map(r => {
      if(typeof unique[r.id] === 'undefined') unique[r.id] = {...r, duplicate:0}
      else unique[r.id].duplicate++
    })
    unique = Object.values(unique)
    console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
    var unique = data.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(t=>(t.id === v.id))===i)

    for(let obj of data){
        unique.find(function(item, i){
            if(item.id == obj.id){
                if(unique[i]["count"]) 
                    unique[i]["count"] += 1
                else
                    unique[i]["count"] = 1;
                
                return i;
            }
            });
        }

    return (
        <div>
        {unique.map(({id, name, count}, index)=>
            <p key={index}>{id}  {name} {count}</p>
        )}
        </div>
        
        )
```

The output will be:

```
555 Sales 3

777 Accounts Payable 2

888 IT 2
```